# Use Guice with Akka Cluster

Tags: scala, akka, guice, akka-cluster, typesafe

Will there be any problems if you use GUICE with Akka Cluster with regard to that will run multiple JVMs? What problems may occur if actively to use GUICE? Or better get rid of it and try to do everything the built-in tools?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you concerned about Guice with Akka Cluster? Guice is for Dependency Injection; as long as your actors are injected correctly, using Guice or Spring, it does not matter. When you obtain your remote ActorRef the executing actor can reside in any of the nodes in the cluster.